# Left-censoring in time series data

Tags: distributions, bayesian, multivariate-analysis, censoring, tobit-regression

This is from a Bayesian problem I'm working on. I have worked out
\begin{align}
f(y_1,...,y_T|\varphi)=f(y_1|\varphi)f(y_2|y_1,\varphi)...f(y_T|y_1,y_2,...,y_{T-1},\varphi),
\end{align}
and all terms in the equation above are known.

Now let $X=(x_1,...,x_T)$ with $x_i=y_i$ if $y_i>0$ and $x_i=0$ if $y_i\le0$. How do I calculate $f(x_i,...,x_T|\varphi)$?

This is a bit like the tobit model but $f(y_i)$ is unknown in my case, I only have their conditional density..

Many thanks!

Comment: This question is posted simultaneously on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/671972/15941) as well.

Comment: Take T=1.  How do you calculate $f(x_1|\varphi)$ from $f(y_1|\varphi)$?  (from X you can calculate Y. Reverse case, you require some assumption.)

Comment: Umm I don't think you can calculate Y from X. Because for $X=0$ you only know $Y\le0$ but don't know the exact values.. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: You are right.. it is in the other way.

Comment: Can you define the notation?

Answer (score 2):

Let $c(x|y)$ be your censoring function.  Then
$$
f(x_1,...,x_T) = \int_{y_1} \cdots \int_{y_T} f(y_1,...,y_T) \prod_{i=1}^T c(x_i|y_i) dy_i
$$
Note that if any $x_i > 0$ then $c(x_i|y_i)$ forces $y_i = x_i$ and the integral over that $y_i$ disappears.  You are only left with integrals over the $y$'s where $x_i=0$.